# Get type object defined inside doctest by type name

Tags: python, python-module, doctest, getattr

I am trying to doc-test a method that accepts a module object `module` and a string with the name of the type `type_name` inside that module :

```
def get_type_from_string(module, type_name):
    """
    >>> class A: pass
    >>> A.__module__
    'mymodule'
    >>> get_type_from_string(sys.modules['mymodule'], 'A')
    <class '__mymodule__.A'>    <------ fails
    """
    return getattr(module, type_name)
```

When I am trying to get the type object with `getattr` (in reality, the method does more than just that), I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'mymodule' has no attribute 'A'
```

**Is it possible to doc-test this method without having to define the `A` class outside of the doc-test?**

Comment: How did you import the `mymodule` and where is the `doctest.testmod()` called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the defined `A class` is not present in the `__dict__`. Maybe this is a problem with the **doctest** itself. As a work around you can add it like this:

`sys.modules[A.__module__].A = A`

or

`sys.modules[A.__module__].__dict__['A'] = A`

```
def get_type_from_string(module, type_name):
    """
    >>> import sys
    >>> class A: pass
    >>> A.__module__
    'mymodule'
    >>> sys.modules[A.__module__].A = A
    >>> get_type_from_string(sys.modules['mymodule'], 'A')
    <class 'mymodule.A'>
    """
    return getattr(module, type_name)
```

This is how I am calling the test:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # import sys
    import doctest
    import mymodule
    doctest.testmod(mymodule)
```